# Find a row with nvarchar column that have a int value between two values in middle of string in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a `nvarchar` column that have values like

> '21:15:00 monday 1390/09/10 morning'

I want to select rows that have a third part (meaning: '1390/09/10') between '1390/09/07' AND '1390/09/15'. I don't want to change the structure of column values to bring the third part to start or end of the string for some reasons. I tried this

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE column BETWEEN '%1390/09/07%' AND '%1390/09/15%'

but it won't work.

I used [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008).

Comment: What RDBMS? You should restructure your table into 1NF anyway. You shouldn't have to decompose column values to do this type of query.

Comment: @Martin Smith so you mean we can't do something like this ?

Comment: You **can** do but this is completely unindexable so your queries will always have to scan all rows as well as being unnecessarily complex and having problems with validating the data.

Comment: @Martin Smith I got your point. can you tell me where i do wrong to got the answer for my query

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS you are using, it would be possible using regular expressions.. and.. depending on the purpose/intention of this query, even doing it that way at all would be much more expensive than normalizing your table, as Martin stated. Update your post to indicate the RDBMS to increase the odds of you getting an answer. Still.. this may be a "bad" schema, again, depending on your intentions for the column and for extracting the data you mentioned...

Comment: @hamze - First, we need to know what database engine and version are you using

Comment: Which DB you are using ? Please provide version detail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the date you have to do this:

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(100) ='21:15:00 monday 1390/09/10 morning'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, SUBSTRING(@t,  PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%',@t),10),111)
```

I used DateTime2 as I used SQL Server 2008.

I hope this help you.